# Mount the `unified' cgroup

Tags: ubuntu, mount

For one of my experiments, I moved to Ubuntu 22.04 from 20.04.

I used to work with the `/sys/fs/cgroup/unified/` directory on Ubuntu 20.04 but I cannot find it in Ubuntu 22.04 Beta version (my testbed machine only has support for the Beta version). Instead, I see the following files in `/sys/fs/cgroup/`:

```
/sys/fs/cgroup$ ls
cgroup.controllers      cpuset.cpus.effective  io.pressure                    sys-kernel-config.mount
cgroup.max.depth        cpuset.mems.effective  io.prio.class                  sys-kernel-debug.mount
cgroup.max.descendants  cpu.stat               io.stat                        sys-kernel-tracing.mount
cgroup.procs            dev-hugepages.mount    memory.numa_stat               system.slice
cgroup.stat             dev-mqueue.mount       memory.pressure                user.slice
cgroup.subtree_control  init.scope             memory.stat
cgroup.threads          io.cost.model          misc.capacity
cpu.pressure            io.cost.qos            sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
```

Although, from the [Ubuntu manpage](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man7/cgroups.7.html) it seems it should have automatically mounted the cgroup2 fs at `unified`:

> Note  that  on many modern systems, systemd(1) automatically mounts the cgroup2 filesystem
> at /sys/fs/cgroup/unified during the boot process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a `systemd` behavior. The `cgroups(7)` documentation about this behavior appears to not have been updated. It still considers the system will have an hybrid v1/v2 setup configured by systemd, while newer systems (than this documentation) will usually have cgroups v2 *only*.

The relevant documentation: [systemd CGROUP_DELEGATION](https://systemd.io/CGROUP_DELEGATION/#three-different-tree-setups-):

> Three Different Tree Setups
>
> systemd supports three different modes how cgroups are set up.
> Specifically:
>
> 1. **Unified** — this is the simplest mode, and exposes a pure cgroup v2 logic. **In this mode `/sys/fs/cgroup` is the only mounted cgroup
>    API file system** and all available controllers are exclusively
>    exposed through it.
> 2. **Legacy** — this is the traditional cgroup v1 mode. In this mode the various controllers each get their own cgroup file system mounted
>    to `/sys/fs/cgroup/<controller>/`. On top of that systemd manages its
>    own cgroup hierarchy for managing purposes as `/sys/fs/cgroup/systemd/`.
> 3. **Hybrid** — this is a hybrid between the unified and legacy mode. It’s set up mostly like legacy, except that **there’s also an additional hierarchy `/sys/fs/cgroup/unified/` that contains the cgroup
>    v2 hierarchy.** [...]

So despite the names involved, losing the directory `/sys/fs/cgroup/unified/` means your system went from the *hybrid* v1+v2 tree setup to the *unified* v2-only tree setup. That's on systems more modern that the modern systems documented in `cgroups(7)` because that's supposed to mean there is no legacy software still expecting cgroup v1 installed on it.